# Azure Front Door polling backend pool state several times per second

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

In our web site we have a route /health/xxx, where you can check the health of the site. In the xxx part you can add anything so we can distinguish different pollers. We are now seeing that Azure Front Door is polling the site several times per second. All polls are returning http status 200 and the site is running.

What could be the cause of Front door polling so often. Also we have specified the probes to be done with https but they are done with http.

**Settings**

[image]

**Logs**

> 2020-02-04T08:31:14.788625531Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:14.889718097Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:15.056720867Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:15.108005604Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:15.694524409Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:16.228060671Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:16.531979272Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:16.566820933Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:16.588722534Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:17.950628116Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:17.992829110Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:18.337208799Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:18.392764355Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:18.421466287Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:18.529090784Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:18.743391272Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:18.777998932Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:18.962965185Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor
>   2020-02-04T08:31:19.251694816Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor

Answer (score 2):

> - **HTTP** or **HTTPS** is NOT **HTTP/1.1**

**HTTP/1.1** shows the current protocol for your web application. The probe is done through **https** only. HTTP/1.1 is the specification for HTTP or HTTPS protocol.

**Update 1:**

---

For example - please refer to the image below taken from Fiddler for an HTTPS request:
[image]

You can observe that the request is using HTTPS protocol but it belongs to [HTTP/1.1 protocol specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec1.html).

---

For the frequent probing - it's the default behavior of Azure Front Door. It keep polling the health probe to decide the fastest/best server from the backend pool where it will route the first request it receives.

> Front Door environments periodically sends a synthetic HTTP/HTTPS request to each of your configured backends. Front Door then uses responses from these probes to determine the **"best"** backends to which it should route real client requests.

Ref: [Health Probes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-health-probes)

---

> **For faster failovers**, set the interval to a lower value. The lower the value, the higher the health probe volume your backends receive. For example, if the interval is set to 30 seconds with 90 Front Door environments or POPs globally, each backend will receive about 3-5 probe requests per second.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-backend-pool

---

Not all the edge will probe your backend, just the nearest ones closest to the ones receiving the requests. Refer to this video to understand how it works in details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The updates that we are seeing are http and not https, as per the log above (http://ourappservice.azurewebsites.net/health/frontdoor). How many edge locations are there? Since we are seeing ~3 rps and the internal is set at 30s, it should indicate over 150 edge locations doing the polling. Can this be true?

Comment: I've added more details to the answer, the polling doesn't happen from all the edges every time.